# Как подогнать картинку из drawable под любой экран?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

Есть программа для работы с изображениями которые размещены в папке drawable и мне нужно поставить картинку на фон телефона, но если я даже беру достаточно маленькую картинку то она все равно как-то непонятно растягивается и получается некрасиво. Как мне подогнать картинку под размеры экрана без сильной потери в качестве. Возможно я не сильно понятно объяснил свой вопрос если что спрашивайте буду объяснять в комментах.

Comment: про scaleType в ImageView читали?

Comment: нет, если поможет то будет хорошо